# Listen for message in content script from addon code

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Addon code,
Creates a `Panel`, populated by `confirmPanel.html`
Listens for a `getPreferences` message from content script,
builds a JSON string and tries to send back to content script ..

```
var confirmPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 450,
    height: 350,
    contentURL: Data.get("confirmPanel.html"),
});

confirmPanel.port.on("getPreferences", function() {

    var prefs = '{'
        +'"fileName":"HelloWorld.txt", '
        +'"pathToFile":"/home/rob/", '
        +'}';

    confirmPanel.port.emit("prefs", prefs);
})
```

`confirmPanel.html` specifies `Panel` contents ..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="confirmPanel.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="Addon_Panel.getPreferences()">
    </body>
</html>
```

`confirmPanel.js` is content script for `confirmPanel.html`
Waits for `body` to load and then sends `getPreferences` message to addon code.
Then waits for `prefs` message from addon code to log the JSON string to console
but `console.log(prefs);` is never executed?

```
var Addon_Panel = {

    getPreferences: function() {
        addon.port.emit("getPreferences", '');
    }
};

addon.port.on("prefs", function (prefs) {
    console.log(prefs);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attached content script as file instead of including it in the html
main.js

```
var confirmPanel = require("sdk/panel").Panel({
    width: 450,
    height: 350,
    contentURL: Data.get("html/confirmPanel.html"),
    contentScriptFile: [Data.get("js/confirmPanel.js")]
});

confirmPanel.port.emit("prefs", prefs);
```

In content script file ..

```
self.port.on("prefs", function (prefs) {
    console.log("in content script");
});
```